# Convergence of a sequence of real matrices

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $A_k\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Assume for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, 
$$\|A_{k+1}\|_{\rm F}\leq \|A_{k}\|_{\rm F},\qquad{\rm and}\qquad \lim_{k\to\infty}(A_k-A_{k-1})=0.$$
Can we prove or disprove by counter-example that $A_k$ converges?

---

$\|A\|_{\rm F}$ is the Frobenius norm of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $a_k $ to be $$0,\frac12,1,\frac23,\frac13,0,\frac14,\frac24,\frac34,1,\ldots $$
Then $|a_k|\leq1$, $a_k-a_{k+1}\to0$, but the sequence does not converge.
Now form $$A_k=\begin {bmatrix}a_k&(1-a_k^2)^{1/2}\\0&0\end{bmatrix} $$ for $n=2$, or the analog (just with more zeroes) for bigger $n $. Then $\|A_k\|_F=1$ for all $k $, $\lim A_k-A_{k+1}=0$, but the sequence does not converge.

Comment: Your example is not monotonic.

Comment: Of course not. The word "monotonic" is not in your question; and, even then, you would have to tell us what "monotonic" means for matrices.

Comment: Since you assumed $n=1$, then I think $\|A_{k+1}\|_{\rm F}\leq\|A_k\|_{\rm F}$ in my question, means monotonic.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I think I can modify my example.

Comment: Thanks, I bet there is a counterexample.

Comment: Please see the edit.